# Java Timestamp e MySQL Timestamp

Tags: java, mysql, timestamp

### Problema:

Estou armazenando um timestamp no MYSQL, porém quando resgato esse timestamp estou perdendo os milésimos.

Timestamp do Java com milésimos.
[image: Timestamp do Java com milésimos]

Timestamp do MYSQL sem milésimos.
[image: Timestamp do MYSQL sem milésimos.]

Por que isso ocorrer?

Como resolver isso?

Preciso do retorno com esses milésimos.

editado:

Acredito que o mysql 5.1.62, não guarde os milesegundos, então parte pra minha solução seria capturar o timeStamp e remover os milliseconds, qual forma eficiente para fazer isso?

Comment: Acredito que o date time do MySQL não chegue a esse nível de precisão. Sei que no SQL Server existe o tipo `datetime2` com esse nível de precisão

Comment: Por curiosidade: que aplicação você está desenvolvendo que precisa desse nível de precisão (milisegundos)?

Comment: Posso ficar sem os milsegundos do timestamp, mas como desenvolvedor seria interessante entender esse comportamento.
Outra questão é que de todas as formas que tentei obter o timestamp no Java ele vem com milisegundos.
`System.currentTimeMillis()`, `Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis()`, `new Date().getTime();` e `new Timestamp().getTime();` não queria ter que remover os milisegundos na marra.

Comment: Versão do MySQL ? Segundos fracionados é uma feature nova no MySQL: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/5.6/en/news-5-6-4.html

Comment: A versão do meu MySQL é 5.1.62, qual a melhor forma de pegar um timestamp no Java onde consiga sempre zerar os milesegundos, assim parte do meu problema acaba.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Respondendo sua pergunta:

> qual a melhor forma de pegar um timestamp no Java onde consiga sempre zerar os milesegundos?

Para os casos:

> System.currentTimeMillis(), Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis(), new Date().getTime(); e new Timestamp().getTime();

Você diz não querer remover na marra, não sei bem o jeito que você usou, mas a forma mais simples que imagino fazer isso é dividindo por 1000 e em seguida multiplicando por 1000. Assim você desconsidera os últimos três dígitos da sua data, que correspondem ao milisegundos. Assim:

```
new Timestamp((System.currentTimeMillis()/1000)*1000);
```

Exemplo:

```
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

public class TesteTimestamp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        timestampComMili(System.currentTimeMillis());
        timestampSemMili(System.currentTimeMillis());

        timestampComMili(Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis());
        timestampSemMili(Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis());

        timestampComMili(new Date().getTime());
        timestampSemMili(new Date().getTime());

        //timestampComMili(new Timestamp().getTime());
        //timestampSemMili(new Timestamp().getTime());
        /* O código acima não é possível, pois não existe um 
         * construtor padrão a classe Timestamp. Veja em:
         * http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html
         */
    }
    public static void timestampComMili(long l) {
        System.out.println("Com mili: " + new Timestamp(l));
    }
    public static void timestampSemMili(long l) {
        System.out.println("Sem mili: " + new Timestamp((l/1000)*1000));
    }
}
```

Resultado:

> Com mili: 2014-09-16 09:48:41.186
>   Sem mili: 2014-09-16 09:48:41.0
>   Com mili: 2014-09-16 09:48:41.198
>   Sem mili: 2014-09-16 09:48:41.0
>   Com mili: 2014-09-16 09:48:41.198
>   Sem mili: 2014-09-16 09:48:41.0

Comment: Ajudou bastante, a ideia de não ter os "mili" é por que sempre dava diferença em comparação de datas por causa dos "mili", mas já está resolvido.

Exemplo populava um objeto, o timestamp do objeto tinha os "mili", passava para o banco e depois fazia uma consulta para saber se tudo foi cadastrado com sucesso. Quando ia comparar os objetos com o equals ou de qualquer outra forma, justamente os "mili" do primeiro objeto eram diferente do retorno do banco. Então acabava ignorando as "datas", mas com isso posso comparar os "timestamp". O banco guarda os "mili". Meio bobo, mas aconteceu. haha

Answer (score 1):

No `MySQL 5.6` você já conseguiria precisão de milisegundos.

tente

`select sysdate(6)` vai retornar `2013-04-16 13:47:56.273434`

e

`select sysdate(3)` vai retornar `2013-04-16 13:47:56.273`

---

Mas caso não queira migrar para o `MySQL 5.6`, você pode usar a função [`DATE_FORMAT()`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_format.asp).

Segue um exemplo:

```
DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%b %d %Y %h:%i %p') resultado: Aug 19 2014 12:45 PM
DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%m-%d-%Y')          resultado: 08-19-2014
DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%d %b %y')          resultado: 19 Aug 14
DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%d %b %Y %T:%f')    resultado: 19 Aug 2014 12:47:10:214
```

Comment: Perco os milesegundos quando cadastro o timestamp, por tanto mesmo que consiga usar o `DATE_FORMAT(create_in,'%d %b %Y %T:%f') ` não daria certo. Nesse caso pode até funcionar por que usa o NOW() é uma DATA completa.